# How to write Graham's number in LaTeX?

Tags: number

I'm looking to write this image in LaTeX but every attempt has ended in failure. Help would be appreciated.

[image: Graham's Number]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 19):

Nice problem. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cdotfill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss\textperiodcentered\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\uparrows}[1]{% #1 is a length
  \mathrel{\underbrace{\makebox[#1][s]{$\uparrow\uparrow$\cdotfill$\uparrow$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\left.
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{rc}
G={}
& 3 \uparrows{7em} 3 \\
& 3 \uparrows{6em} 3 \\
& \underbrace{\makebox[5em]{\vdots}} \\
& 3 \uparrows{4em} 3\\
& 3 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3
\end{array}
\right\}
64\text{ layers}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Playing a bit with the lenghts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cdotfill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss\textperiodcentered\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\uparrows}[1]{% #1 is a length
  \mathrel{\underbrace{\makebox[#1][s]{$\uparrow\uparrow$\cdotfill$\uparrow$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\left.
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{rc}
G={}
& 3 \uparrows{9em} 3 \\
& 3 \uparrows{7.5em} 3 \\
& \underbrace{\makebox[6em]{\vdots}} \\
& 3 \uparrows{4.5em} 3\\
& 3 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3
\end{array}
\right\}
64\text{ layers}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]